# How to declare enum with Vector3 Directions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, vector, enums

In an example found in W3Schools, I saw that you can give a custom value to an Enum, like this:

```
enum Months
{
  January,    // 0
  February,   // 1
  March=6,    // 6
  April,      // 7
  May,        // 8
  June,       // 9
  July        // 10
}
```

For my game, I often have to check the neighbors of a certain position (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT), so I made this array:

```
Vector3Int[] neighborOffsets =
        {
            new Vector3Int(0, -1, 0), // Bottom
            new Vector3Int(-1, 0, 0), // Left 
            new Vector3Int(0, 1, 0), // Top
            new Vector3Int(1, 0, 0) // Right
        };
```

However, if I require a specific and known value, I have to remember which position to access by it's index. So if I explicitly need the TOP direction, I'd have to write: `neighborOffsets[2]`.

Is there an easier way to do this with enums? Something like this:

```
public enum Directions
{
   BOTTOM = new Vector3Int(0, -1, 0),
   LEFT = new Vector3Int(-1, 0, 0), 
   TOP = new Vector3Int(0, 1, 0), 
   RIGHT = new Vector3Int(1, 0, 0) 
}
```

So then if I need the UP direction, I'd just write Directions.TOP?

Comment: This already exists in unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3Int.html so just copy this; is it just the syntax that you are looking for? Use a static property, e.g. `public static Vector3Int bottom = new Vector3Int(0, -1, 0)`, then access by type name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @Charleh in the comment:

This already exists in unity: [Vector3Int](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3Int.html) so just copy this; is it just the syntax that you are looking for? Use a static property, e.g. `public static Vector3Int bottom = new Vector3Int(0, -1, 0)`, then access by type name.